# Make Emulator of Asus google nexus 7

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have android sdk , updated to latest version(v21).

Now what i want is :

1. **Make emulator of Asus google nexus 7, that contains 800 x 1280 resolution and 216 dpi.**
2. **As i updated my sdk to latest version i can not edit my current dpi of emulator.**

Please help me to create this AVD.

Comment: Why not just use the supplied device definition from Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make emulator of Asus google nexus 7, that contains 800 x 1280
>   resolution and 216 dpi.

To make emulator same as **Google Asus Nexus 7** you will get this as default device while creating new AVD.

> As i updated my sdk to latest version i can not edit my current dpi of
>   emulator.

for this you can delete and can create New Emulator from latest AVD with the Below suggestions.

After Update your ADT to version 21.

**In Older Version each time you have to set `Add Custom` Screen if you want custom Device Configurations as (if you want Nexus 4).**

In ADT21 version you can get this thing done by

> **open `AVD Manager`, u can define your custom screen in `"Device Definition"`**

**Alternative (Much Easier approach)**

> in Newest Version you Don't Need to Set Custom Device
>   Configurations from the above Suggestion as much easier way is available for it. you >Just Have to Make Emulator With your Device 
>   Configurations and after you will see those Configurations with
>   Emulator Name Inside `Graphical Layout` of XML

like after Created my Emulator of Nexus7 Emulator with Android 4.2 with Name as "Nexus7_Android_4.2" i will get this Device Configuration in Graphical Layout of xml automatically.

Below is the Screen Shot of it.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.