# How to create 7" Tablet (1280 * 800) Screen Resolution Emulator in Oracle Virtual box?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Emulator of Asus google nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064998/make-emulator-of-asus-google-nexus-7)

I am trying configure to **7" Tablet (1280 * 800) Screen with dpi=216** Resolution Emulator in **Oracle Virtual box** .but I can't solve my problem.

*My Emulator working fine in Oracle Virtual Box.*

I am use following link.
http://www.andreybutov.com/2011/10/14/how-to-set-up-a-faster-android-emulator/

Please help,how to configure 7 inch (1280 * 800 )tablet  dpi=216 virtual box.

Comment: `can't solve my problem` Which problem? You say directly after that: `My Emulator working fine in Oracle Virtual Box.` So please clear up your issue. I don't get what you really want.

Comment: working fine means running perfect but resolution and 7 inch screen problem.

Comment: The question is to create emulator for Virtual box and NOT for native application. Can someone please help?